# Good sources for reading Operating Systems

Tags: c, multithreading, process, synchronization

I am looking for some good online sources which explain process sychronization,process and threads with practical examples.

i have gone through a lot of theoritical stuff but always face confusion and difficulties when actually trying implement them.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=7953)  where you can find the code very useful for thread synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

I started on Tanenbaum's [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) "Modern Operating Systems" book then moved on to Linux From Scratch. For practical examples OSDev [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) and [here](http://forum.osdev.org/) is a mine of information when you become really hands on. Otherwise, for Windows specifics there are no shortage of books or MSDN literature.

I found Tanenbaum a very entertaining read, he invented the Minix OS which he uses for real world examples. Minix is from around the same era as Linux. Have a look at some of the very early Linux source code release (eg 0.1 or therabouts if you don't want to lose a year of your life studying pure code).

Comment: Minix is actually quite a bit older than Linux -- though Linux may seem older, since it's mostly a clone of an even older system.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization) Is Always The Best Online Tutorial Guide. However u can also Check [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb809047.aspx) Link.. If you would like to go with a [Pdf Book then u can click Here.. Its really Good Book](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3antaV-w2HM5cJ%3awww.home.agilent.com/agilent/redirector.jspx?ckey%3D66304%26action%3Dref%26lc%3Deng%26cc%3DCA%26cname%3DAGILENT_EDITORIAL+network+synchronization&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiZ8JzPlqUAYBNueBc5MGN3H0HgzPaXlMZyMV1RhxBfR5Xektjx_7mNWmYtDIDsZLGLC5a05W5ViM0xyDa8nmRVa30_QNgHPeXYUQiczxeabKRdop1aHZXAyXQgxf_aX57h5o9h&sig=AHIEtbRRQ44PjyzZTfXBz6qU4Vw7SIpzeQ&pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

this link for [NACHOS](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/tom/nachos/) may be a good help for you. In our undergraduate class we did some good assignments in OS course.